# not seeing code on jsfiddle, only result

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I keep looking at jsfiddle's posted on other questions here, but for some reason I can only see the results and not the code

At first it seemed like this was happening randomly but now it seems pretty consistent

How can a JSfiddle render a result without any code?

I'm not sure what is happening actually. But I'm seeing this in firefox and chrome. Here is the latest example http://jsfiddle.net/vikikamath/QU6WP/1/

thanks for any insight

obligatory code that I will ask about if I can't view that jsfiddle

```
<div id="graphcontent">
            <strong></strong>
        </div>
        <div id="subcontent" class="line">Open Requests<div id="count">13</div></div>
        <div id="subcontent" class="line_completed">Completed Requests</div>
```

Comment: You mean you don't see the HTML or CSS?

Comment: i'm using chrome dev channel and i also can't see the code on jsfiddle. It's usual that they break things on dev channel. But it works fine in firefox.

Comment: It would help to see a screenshot of what it looks like for you.

Comment: Please specify exactly what you are not seeing. There are separate windows for HTML, CSS, javascript and output. Simply saying "code" is not clear at all. HTML is not code, it is markup and neither is CSS.

Comment: @PaulSasik I wasn't seeing HTML, CSS or JS, only the results pane. But its better now after doing the multiple refreshes. Its tricky to remember how to ACTUALLY refresh a page across multiple browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jsFiddle has recently (actually quite a while back) switched to a new design, and the old design (cached by the browsers) stopped working (CSS, HTML and javascript all showed a blank frame).

If you see a blue favicon (the old one; the new one is black) and a toolbar with gradient (the new one are just single-color rectangles for buttons), it's time to reload. Not an ordinary reload, you need <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: and i was blaming chrome dev for breaking things again.

Comment: quite a while back? like in the last two weeks? Where do you get info about that site (maybe a twitter page?), clicking the logo just takes you to a new fiddle

Comment: @CQM Just by using it - At first, I thought it was a temporary issue. After a while, I've decided to do some research. The research turned out there was a design update to the site (unpopular among some). I hadn't seen any change, so I force-refreshed and voila, the issue was gone.